# Сообщение-ответ низкого качества, содержащее решение

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Всем доброго дня. Следующий вопрос у меня. Наткнулся на сообщение низкого качества, вот это [Необходимо перевести SQL запрос в LINQ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571206/189339) зашел, почитал комментарии, а там уже написали, чтобы внес правку в ответ. Так вот...качество у ответа низкое, но решение все же было достигнуто именно благодаря этому ответу. Удаляется ли такой ответ? Исходя из комментариев я его не стал удалять, так как автору уже сказали внести правку...я в смятении.

Comment: Уже сказали и внесена - разные вещи. Но раз уж ответ был найден, то можно и оставить.

Comment: @Other, вот поэтому и спросил, оставлять ли такие ответы

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это не ответ. Он не содержит ответа на вопрос - результата перевода. Это *совет* воспользоваться утилитой. Совет хороший, он от этого он ответом на становится.

Конкретный пример - на многие вопросы можно ответить *советом*

> Купи пару хороших книг, почитай статьи, наберись опыта, и наверняка сможешь нати решение!

Или даже более конкретным *советом*, который почти наверняка приведет автора к решению, если автор ему последует:

> В книге ZZZZZ, в главе XX эта тема отлично раскрыта! Почитай и все поймешь!

Или достойной альтернативой:

> Ответ есть по первой ссылке в гугле по словам "ZZZZ EEEE"!

Советы полезны. Но ответами они не являются.

Comment: так вот и я об этом... но в комментариях написано, чтобы он внес правку, а вдруг правка будет действенной и сделает ответ наполненным большим смыслом?

Comment: @DenisBubnov править можно и удаленные ответы. если правка будет действенной - ответ восстановят.

Comment: Ответ был удален модератором?

Comment: @alexolut сконвертирован в комментарий

Comment: @PashaPash стоит добавить, что на обновления удаленных вопросов не генерируется никаких оповещений и модератора нужно уведомлять явно, тревогой.